# Help understanding CAN-bus signals to control camera module

Tags: can-bus, range-rover

Replaced car head unit with carplay (2011 Range Rover L322) and everything works except rearview camera. The input on the head unit works but the car doesn't send video signal when needed. Here is the description:

1. car has video control module that has 5 separate camera inputs. Then, based on what view driver selects, signal is sent to the video control module to activate appropriate camera and send video signal to the head unit.
2. [Here](https://www.fullfatrr.com/gallery/albums/userpics/15719/Multiple%20cameras%7E0.pdf) is the wiring diagram I found online.
3. and Below is the image that describes the components.

I have done some Arduino projects but this certainly seems to be over my head.

Question: is there a way to decipher how car activates the cameras so that I can then replicate it with some Arduino setup? I was told that the two yellow wires in the middle of the green plug are from can-bus.

Or, alternatively, can I just make an Arduino project to switch and activate different cameras? Will the fact that they use LVDS signal get in a way of just using relays to connect appropriate camera signals to go to the head unit?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It might be a little helpful if you'd include what the year/make/model of the vehicle involved is ... hard to even start helping you without that information.

Comment: sorry, I used short-hand for that info: (2011 RR L322 - 2011 Range Rover L322 (full-size range rover)