# Translating 5-wire camera input to composite signal

Tags: backup-camera

Existing OEM rearview camera has 5 wires (V+, LVDS+, LVDS-, LIN, ground). Is there a way to translate (hook up) this to a standard composite cable that goes into back of a aftermarket head unit?

All the cameras I have dealt with before had up to four cables (two for video in composite cable and up to two for power (or signal to turn power to to the camera).

[Here](https://www.fullfatrr.com/gallery/albums/userpics/15719/Multiple%20cameras%7E0.pdf) is a wiring diagram and I am just looking to hook up rearview camera (there are total of 5 OEM cameras controlled by CAN-BUS but it's over my head and want to bypass the entire module altogether.). [Here](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/87637/help-understanding-can-bus-signals-to-control-camera-module) is the original question that I am afraid is too complex and not worth tackling.

So, any help for hooking up the 5 wire set-up to a regular composite video input will be great. thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sure this is possible technically but I believe that the topic is far outside the Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair topic.  You might ask this in the Electrical Engineering topic area.

Comment: Thank you. I will add it there. Upon the initial searching, there were many similar questions (about CAN-BUS) under the automotive, hence my initial post here but you are correct